# Kotlin inline value class - cannot override hashCode() function

Tags: kotlin, hashcode, value-class

I just cannot override hashCode() function on value class.
minimal example (I know that in this example there is no need to override it...)

```
@JvmInline
value class Identifier(val value: String){
    override fun hashCode(): Int = this.value.hashCode()
}
```

I get error: Member with the name 'hashCode' is reserved for future releases

Edit: Is there any way to specify own hashCode() function?

Comment: That is correct. You cannot override it. What exactly is your question?

Comment: why? and is there any workaround?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of right now, you cannot override the `equals` or `hashCode` method of value classes. The [language specification](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/declarations.html#value-class-declaration) explicitly disallows this:

> Value classes must adhere to the following limitations:
>
> - [...]
> - They must not override `equals` and `hashCode` member functions of `kotlin.Any`
> - [...]

This is because the developers of Kotlin are planning to add a strongly typed `equals` method that you can override.

From the [inline classes proposal](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/inline-classes.md#methods-from-kotlinany):

> Methods from `Any` (`toString`, `hashCode`, `equals`) can be useful for a user-defined inline classes and therefore should be customizable. Methods `toString` and `hashCode` can be overridden as usual methods from `Any`. For method `equals` we're going to introduce new operator that represents "typed" `equals` to avoid boxing for inline classes:

```
@JvmInline
value class Identifier(val value: String){
    override fun hashCode(): Int = ...

    operator fun equals(other: Identifier): Boolean = ...
}
```

This is so that when you use `==` on value classes with a custom `equals`, you don't have to box them every time as you are passing it to the `Any?` parameter on the `Any.equals` method. The compiler would also automatically generate an `equals(Any?)` implementation from your `equals(Identifier)` implementation.

But they haven't implemented this feature *yet*. This is why they don't let you implement `hashCode` - because if you do, you would most likely also need to implement `equals(Any?)` (it is rarely useful/correct to just implement `hashCode`), but that means your code would break in future versions of Kotlin! In future versions, you would need to implement `equals(Identifier)`, not `equals(Any?)`.

So you can only wait until this feature gets added. Until then, you cannot have `hashCode` and `equals` that does not delegate to the wrapped value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation, however I was afraid of this.